# fillna with linear regression model built from two columns in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
    sepal length    sepal width   petal length  petal width     target
0      4.9              3.5            1.4          0.2         setosa
1      4.9              3.0            1.4          0.2         setosa
2      4.7              3.2            1.3          0.2         setosa
3      4.6              3.1            1.5          0.2         setosa
4      5.0              3.6            1.4          NaN         setosa
      ...
```

I've created LinearRegression() model using petal width and petal length. Now I want to use linear_regression model I've trained to fill NaN values.

Here is what I've tried, it works however I am curious to know if there is more efficient way.

```
def fillna_linear_reg(length, width):
    if pd.isna(length):
        pred_length = lin_reg.predict([[width]]) 
        return pred_length[0][0]
    else:
        return length

iris_df["petal length (cm)"] = iris_df.apply(lambda x: fillna_linear_reg(x["petal length (cm)"], x["petal width (cm)"]), axis=1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is a perfectly good method, you could find the Nan and just fill those in, or you could use a multiprocessing pool and fill just the Nan's in parallel...  What do you want to do?

Comment: @PaulBrennan I disagree. apply is highly inefficient. Especially if used in combination with by nature vectorized functions like sklearn predict methods.

Comment: inefficient, yes, completely, but it gets the answer @Ambleu is after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a more efficient way. You could use predict and assign all missing values at once. Avoid using `df.apply` whenever possible. It kills the performance, especially when used with other vectorizable functions like `predict` (or even already vectorized) methods of (I assume so) `sklearn` models.

```
def fillna_linear_reg(lin_reg, length, width):
    nan_mask = length.isna()
    pred_length = lin_reg.predict(width.loc[nan_mask])
    length.loc[nan_mask] = pred_length

fillna_linear_reg(
    lin_reg, iris_df.loc[:, "petal length (cm)"], iris_df.loc[:, "petal width (cm)"]
)
```

Depending on the machine learning module you used for training, you may need to pass the x-data to the `predict` method as a 2d-array and squeeze back to a 1d-array. If so, you can replace the line including the prediction with:

```
pred_length = np.squeeze(lin_reg.predict(np.atleast_2d(width.loc[nan_mask])))
```

This can be of course simplified, if you add explicit shape information.

Comment: I guess you need to add the batch dimension first before passing it to predict ..In the similar way when assigning value back to length you need to remove batch dimensions...

Comment: @ShubhamSharma true, thanks for mentioning it. I added a small edit to cope with predict methods requiring 2d-inputs.